# CS1519 for C# in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding and have encountered an error with the code and I'm unsure how to fix it. I'm using unity 2018 and it tells me -

**error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class AutoCookies : MonoBehaviour {
     public bool CreatingCookie = false;
     public static CookieIncrease = 1; 
     public int InternalIncrease;
 
void Update() {
     InternalIncrease = CookieIncrease;  
    if (CreatingCookie == false)
    {CreatingCookie = true;
    StartCoroutine(CreateTheCookie());
    }
}
IEnumerator CreateTheCookie ()
{
  GlobalCookie.CookieCount += InternalIncrease;
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
  CreatingCookie = false; 
    }
}
```

I've looked at what the error actually means and I've tried to fix it but I've been unsuccessful. The code is designed to auto create cookies for a game I'm coding for my year 12 Major Works.

Comment: `public static CookieIncrease = 1; ` is missing a type

Comment: Welcome to SO! Luckily this is a very simple fix as mentioned by @DanielA.White. If you're unfamiliar with static variables and what they mean, unity has a quick tutorial to help you understand: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/statics-l

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel White said, `public static CookieIncrease = 1;` is the problem.
There is no type definition for CookieIncrease.
`public static int CookieIncrease = 1;` is probably what you were going for.